# Can't mount Volume via Applescript as a login time

Tags: macos, applescript

So I have this script that I saved as an application and added it my login items.

```
tell application "Finder" to mount volume "afp://Data_Cube.local/Scotts Stuff"
delay 5
tell application "iTunes" to activate
```

However when I login I get an error dialog with this message "Connection is invalid.
Finder got an error: Connection is invalid. (-609)"

If I click the edit button in the error dialog it opens up the Script Editor.   I press the run button and the volume is mounted just fine.

Any ideas why my volume won't mount when used as a login item?   FYI I'm using Yosemite.

Comment: it's firing before the network is fully established, maybe? Try giving it some breathing space at the head - delay 60s before your first action then maybe see how much you can reduce that & still be successful

Comment: I tried to add some delays that did help.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
tell application "Finder" to mount volume "afp://Data_Cube.local/Scotts Stuff"
```

to

```
mount volume "afp://Data_Cube.local/Scotts Stuff"
```

seems to be the resolution.  As mount is part of the standard scripting library.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if you're answering your own question.